# How can I get balance of an account in range of defined block numbers?

Tags: go-ethereum

Following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32313312/2402577) guide us how to get the balance of the accounts.

=> How could I get balance of an account in range of some block number. This would help us to observe the balance activity of an account.

For example I have a list of account. I want to get the balance of all of them in between block-number 100 and 1000.

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block number can be passed as the second argument to `web3.eth.getBalance`, like `web3.eth.getBalance(address, 100)`.  You could then loop through block numbers from 100 to 1000.